# How do I stop Spotify from crashing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine, spotify

I am using Spotify on wine on Linux (Ubuntu). It worked fine before, but after I uninstalled and re-installed it, for some reason every time I run it, it doesn't work.

It crashes after I log in. When it crashes I can see the Spotify window. When it crashes, Spotify has a note saying

`We're sorry but you appear to be on an unsupported platform`

In wine configuration, for audio, I have OSS Driver as the only sound driver activated.

```
Hardware Acceleration: Emulation
Default Sample Rate: 44100
Default Bits Per Sample: 16
```

These are the reccomended settings for wine (https://www.spotify.com/us/help/faq/wine/)

The following is the output to the console when I run Spotify:

```
fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"Spotify"): stub
fixme:winsock:WSALookupServiceBeginW (0x12f8ea1c 0x00000ff1 0x1086ff18) Stub!
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled 0x14bfa78
fixme:win:RegisterShellHookWindow (0x3019e): stub
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_get_Enabled 0x14062440, 0x14bf22c
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_ProcessImageFileName 0x14062440, L"C:\\users\\USER\\Application Data\\Spotify\\spotify.exe"
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_Name 0x14062440, L"Spotify"
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_apps_Add 0x14062380, 0x14062440
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser returning no proxy used
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {4df0c730-df9d-4ae3-9153-aa6b82e9795a} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {4df0c730-df9d-4ae3-9153-aa6b82e9795a} could be created for context 0x1
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {4df0c730-df9d-4ae3-9153-aa6b82e9795a} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {4df0c730-df9d-4ae3-9153-aa6b82e9795a} could be created for context 0x1
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6} not registered
fixme:ole:CoGetClassObject CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6} could be created for context 0x17
fixme:advapi:GetCurrentHwProfileW (0x14bf6c0)
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW Option INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION: STUB
fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationProcess (process=0xffffffff) Unimplemented information class: ProcessDebugFlags
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000068 at address 0x681f1fd5 (thread 0041), starting debugger...
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000068 in 32-bit code (0x681f1fd5).
Register dump:
 CS:0073 SS:007b DS:007b ES:007b FS:0033 GS:003b
 EIP:681f1fd5 ESP:15f1e7f4 EBP:15f1e82c EFLAGS:00210212(  R- --  I   -A- - )
 EAX:00000001 EBX:68267ff4 ECX:00000000 EDX:00000005
 ESI:00000054 EDI:00000000
Stack dump:
0x15f1e7f4:  00000028 68203313 14085b38 14085b38
0x15f1e804:  00000054 00000001 00000000 0047d2f9
0x15f1e814:  00000054 00000001 0012c6c0 20574ff4
0x15f1e824:  00000000 00000002 00164df0 0047d099
0x15f1e834:  00164df0 00000013 2056ae6e 00000005
0x15f1e844:  00000000 00000001 00164df0 00000013
Backtrace:
=>0 0x681f1fd5 RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x15() in ntdll (0x15f1e82c)
  1 0x0047d099 in spotify (+0x7d098) (0x00164df0)
  2 0x00700061 in spotify (+0x300060) (0x00720067)
  3 0xfffffd98 (0x85392875)
0x681f1fd5 RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x15 in ntdll: movl  0x14(%esi),%eax
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (120 modules)
PE    400000-  b25000   Export          spotify
ELF 20000000-20062000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  20010000-20062000   \               advapi32
ELF 20062000-2008c000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 2008c000-20139000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  200a0000-20139000   \               winex11
ELF 20139000-2014c000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 2014c000-20282000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 20282000-2029c000   Deferred        libice.so.6
ELF 2029c000-202a2000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF 202a2000-202a6000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 202a6000-202ad000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 202ad000-20346000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  202c0000-20346000   \               winmm
ELF 20346000-203a8000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  20350000-203a8000   \               wininet
ELF 203a8000-204a0000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  203b0000-204a0000   \               comctl32
ELF 204a0000-2054d000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  204b0000-2054d000   \               crypt32
ELF 2054d000-20576000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  20550000-20576000   \               winhttp
ELF 20576000-2067f000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  20590000-2067f000   \               oleaut32
ELF 2067f000-2068d000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 2068d000-206a0000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 206a0000-206a9000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 206a9000-206bb000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.3
ELF 206bb000-20740000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF 20740000-20744000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 20744000-20766000   Deferred        localspl<elf>
  \-PE  20750000-20766000   \               localspl
ELF 20766000-2077b000   Deferred        dwmapi<elf>
  \-PE  20770000-2077b000   \               dwmapi
ELF 2077b000-207d8000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  20780000-207d8000   \               dbghelp
ELF 207d8000-207ec000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  207e0000-207ec000   \               msimg32
ELF 207ec000-2080b000   Deferred        hnetcfg<elf>
  \-PE  207f0000-2080b000   \               hnetcfg
ELF 20da0000-20dda000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  20db0000-20dda000   \               winspool
ELF 2129d000-212c0000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  212a0000-212c0000   \               imm32
ELF 21c47000-21c52000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 262e3000-262fd000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  262f0000-262fd000   \               version
ELF 28623000-2880c000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  28630000-2880c000   \               shell32
ELF 293a7000-294ec000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  293c0000-294ec000   \               user32
ELF 2e67b000-2e6a4000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 2e7a3000-2e7aa000   Deferred        libnss_dns.so.2
ELF 2e889000-2e8db000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 33db4000-33dbd000   Deferred        libsm.so.6
ELF 35527000-3553c000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 37afa000-37b11000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 3983d000-39866000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  39840000-39866000   \               msacm32
ELF 3ae55000-3ae5b000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 3dea8000-3df0b000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  3deb0000-3df0b000   \               setupapi
ELF 3e168000-3e16c000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 44585000-4461c000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 44c09000-44c3e000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 457fa000-45800000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 496a4000-496bf000   Deferred        spoolss<elf>
  \-PE  496b0000-496bf000   \               spoolss
ELF 4a78d000-4a7b2000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  4a790000-4a7b2000   \               mpr
ELF 4c773000-4c89b000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  4c790000-4c89b000   \               ole32
ELF 4cb42000-4cb78000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  4cb50000-4cb78000   \               uxtheme
ELF 4fe73000-4fe89000   Deferred        midimap<elf>
  \-PE  4fe80000-4fe89000   \               midimap
ELF 527c7000-527e0000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  527d0000-527e0000   \               msacm32
ELF 55488000-5548c000   Deferred        libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
ELF 562bd000-56354000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  562d0000-56354000   \               gdi32
ELF 5c861000-5c86c000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 5cd82000-5cd98000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  5cd90000-5cd98000   \               psapi
ELF 5ecb6000-5ecbf000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 5f3ba000-5f3d9000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 6182c000-61875000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 6191b000-619e4000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 64467000-644e3000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  64470000-644e3000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 68000000-68020000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF 68020000-6803b000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF 6803b000-681b7000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF 681b7000-681bc000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF 681bc000-68284000   Export          ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  681d0000-68284000   \               ntdll
ELF 68284000-682ae000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 682ae000-682b8000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 682b8000-682c4000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 682c4000-682d1000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 682d1000-6845b000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  682e0000-6845b000   \               kernel32
ELF 6bf27000-6bf57000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  6bf30000-6bf57000   \               ws2_32
ELF 6fa49000-6fa6b000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  6fa50000-6fa6b000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 717c1000-717ca000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 735b5000-735b9000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 75a3e000-75a43000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 75c37000-75ca1000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  75c40000-75ca1000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7720f000-772bf000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF 78332000-78370000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 786fa000-7870e000   Deferred        lz32<elf>
  \-PE  78700000-7870e000   \               lz32
ELF 79038000-79056000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7a927000-7a92b000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7b740000-7b759000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7c629000-7c76b000   Deferred        libwine.so.1
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 winecfg.exe
    00000009    0
0000000e services.exe
    00000022    0
    0000001d    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
0000001a mDNSResponder.exe
    0000001e    0
    0000001c    0
    0000001b    0
0000001f winedevice.exe
    00000023    0
    00000021    0
    00000020    0
00000024 explorer.exe
    00000025    0
00000015 (D) C:\users\USER\Application Data\Spotify\spotify.exe
    00000042    0
    00000041    0
    00000040    0 <==
    0000003f    0
    0000003a    0
    00000039    0
    00000038    0
    00000037    0
    00000036    0
    00000035    0
    00000034    0
    00000033    0
    00000032    0
    00000031    0
    00000030    0
    0000002f    0
    0000002e    0
    0000002d    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000045    0
    00000047    0
    00000046    0
    00000044    0
    00000016    0
    00000017    0
    0000000c    0
    0000000d    0
    0000000b    0
Backtrace:
=>0 0x681f1fd5 RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x15() in ntdll (0x15f1e82c)
  1 0x0047d099 in spotify (+0x7d098) (0x00164df0)
  2 0x00700061 in spotify (+0x300060) (0x00720067)
  3 0xfffffd98 (0x85392875)
err:seh:raise_exception Unhandled exception code c0000005 flags 0 addr 0x681f1fd5
err:seh:raise_exception Unhandled exception code c0000005 flags 0 addr 0x681f1fd5
err:seh:setup_exception_record nested exception on signal stack in thread 0042 eip 7904db19 esp 7ff57950 stack 0x168b2000-0x17240000
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any specific advice, but on one Xubuntu machine I installed Spotify on, it always crashed on startup until I *upgraded the BIOS to the latest version*.

On another machine, of a different make, the same thing happened. I didn't try to update the BIOS, but at one point, Spotify just started working; must have been due to the package updates that I'd installed in the meanwhile.